# Цикл запроса mysql php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть такой массив:

```
var treeData = [
    <?php
          $stmt_one = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM dolzhnosti WHERE pod='0'");
while ($row_one = $stmt_one->fetch()) {
    ?>
  {
    "name": "<?php echo $row_one['name'];?>",
    "parent": "null",
    "children": [
          <?php
          $stmt_two = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM dolzhnosti WHERE pod='".$row_one['id']."'");
while ($row_two = $stmt_two->fetch()) {
    ?>
    {
        "name": "<?php echo $row_two['name'];?>",
        "parent": "<?php echo $row_one['name'];?>",
      },
      <?php } ?>
    ]
  },
  <?php } ?>
];
```

Есть таблица

```
+-----+-------+-----+
| id  | name  | pod |
+-----+-------+-----+
|  1  | Name1 |  0  |
|  2  | Name2 |  1  |   
|  3  | Name3 |  2  |   
|  4  | Name4 |  3  |
|  5  | Name5 |  4  |
+-----+--------+----+
```

Как вывести все должности которые подчиняются друг другу, т.к. `Name2` подчиняется `Name1`.
Пока смог вывести только один уровень.

Comment: Про [способы](https://habr.com/ru/post/153861/) хранения в реляционной базе вложенных множеств и работы с ними.

Answer (score 1):

В принципе можно сделать так одним запросом:

```
select d1.id, d1.name as boss, d2.name as podcheneny
from dolzhnosti d1
left join dolzhnosti d2
on d2.pod=d1.id
```

Лучше всего хранить данные в виде `array` или `json`, смотря какая задача.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно вывести только 1 уровень и 2 уровень, то ответ **mepihindeveloper** верный. 
Если нужно вывести несколько, то делаете тот же самый запрос и уже в PHP строите многоуровневую структуру.

Comment: Также можно написать процедуру в БД, которая будет все возвращать. Я такую задачу решал для построения иерархического дерева сотрудников.

Comment: А процедура не будет более ресурсозатратная чем php?

Comment: Пхп работает на стороне сервера, а процедура на стороне базы. Пусть база делает, все равно ей выполнять запросы

Comment: Сторона базы так же на стороне сервера, у нее не отдельные бесконечные ресурсы.  Обычное приложение скорее упадет от переизбытка запросов, чем от лишних циклов php. Хотя в случае процедур не знаю, насколько там тратятся ресурсы. Но если честно сомневаюсь, что 10 запросов, хоть и в процедуре будут выгоднее, нескольких пробегов по массиву в php.